Why are my trees so small?
Sorry I can't figure out a better way to phrase this but when I try to draw trees on a seperate tile map they look really small? I've looked around online and I can't figure out how to fix this

Include the import settings of your tileset or compare the PPU from this tileset to the other tileset

I'll edit the original post now.

ohhhhw :facepalm: i found it- pixels per unit was 100- it was meant to be 16

PPU is always the culprit :) You are allowed to self answer your question, maybe include a screenshot of where to see the ppu or that you compared it to your other tilemap
